# A regular expression related to look-arounds

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Design a regular expression to extract the first two digits of sub-strings which:

1. End with letter
2. Start with a 2

So from `"234b342d3"`, the match result should be:
`23` (from `234b`)
`2d` (from `2d`)

My approximate answer is `"(?=1.*)[a-zA-Z]"`, but looks like it doesn't work.

I will appreciate your every reply.

Comment: Your example doesn't end with a letter. Please give a little more detail, e.g. on how your match result is created.

Comment: I mean extract some subString form "234b342d3" which has letter.
the result "23" is the first two digits of String "234b".the result "2d" is the first two digits of String "2d".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `(?=2.*)...`.

`(?=2.*)` means the next characters are `2` followed by one or more of anything. But then the regex says the next character must be `[a-zA-Z]`, so nothing will ever match (since a character can't be `2` and `[a-zA-Z]` at the same time.

Just removing the look-ahead (`2.*[a-zA-Z]`) is a step in the right direction, but the following is still wrong:

- Won't put the first 2 characters in a group so you can extract it
- Greedy matching (`.*` will match greedily, so `234b342d` instead of just `234b`, and `2d` won't match as it will already have been covered by the previous match)

So put the first 2 characters in brackets to put it in a group and add non-greedy matching (`.*?` instead of `.*`) (`(2.).*?[a-zA-Z]`). But now:

- 2 followed by a letter won't match

So we need to add look-behind to account for that.

**So finally we get:**

```
(2.)((?<=[a-zA-Z])|.*?[a-zA-Z])
```

And then extract the first group (how to do this is language dependent).

`(2.)` makes sure it starts with a 2 and puts the first 2 characters in a group.
`(?<=[a-zA-Z])` is look-behind to account for `2d` in your example (a `2` followed by a letter)
`.*?` is non-greedy matching
`[a-zA-Z]` - means ends with a character

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I finally know how look-arounds works.It's a wonderful day.

Comment: Everyone don't understand look-arounds should read this post.